# iOS app will not run on iPhone iOS 13.6 from Xcode 11.6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run an IOS app on which I am working onto my iPhone. I was able prior to upgrading either my iPhone or XCode – I am not sure exactly when it would not work. The app will work on the simulator but not on the iPhone. The app builds successfully but then I get an error “Unable to launch net.jimbarry.Clima and when I look at the details here is what they say:

```
Details
Unable to launch net.jimbarry.Clima
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: -12

Request to launch net.jimbarry.Clima failed.
Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice
Code: 2
Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch net.jimbarry.Clima because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'net.jimbarry.Clima'.

The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch net.jimbarry.Clima because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: Unable to launch net.jimbarry.Clima because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = Security;
}
```

System Information

- macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
- Xcode 11.6 (16141)
- I have IOS version 13.6 on my iPhone
- I am running MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.5

I tried:

- cleaning my project (CMD + SHIFT + K)
- Restarting XCode
- Restarting the Mac
- Restarting the iPhone

Comment: Also check the listed reasons for the failure: `because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never could get my app to work on my iPhone, so I finally just tried to click on the app icon that had been created previously and a pop up appeared on my screen with the title "Untrusted Developer" followed by "Your device management settings do not allow using apps from developer 'Apple Development: xxxxx on this iPhone. You can allow using these apps in Settings. I then googled the error and this link solved my problem - https://howtoapple.com/how-to-trust-untrusted-enterprise-developer/

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a certificates issue.
If it installs but does not run on device, personally in most of the cases is a wrong certificate set for the debug builds. Either there is an entitlement missing (permissions like location, iCloud, etc) or often i saw this using a release certificate for a debug build, especially if it installs but does not launch.

Comment: But what do I do about a wrong certificate for the debug builds? How do I get the correct certificate? I am not sure how to fix this.